# Reading from text file multiple times in VB.NET

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, multithreading, combobox

I am trying to read from a text file which contains JSON which comes approximately 6~7 mb. There is a combobox, whenever the item in it changes, a thread call is made. In that thread, first the reader reads the text file, then the JSON is decoded and showed in multiple listboxes.

Everything works, but it take nearly 10-15 sec to complete the thread. Am assuming this is because of reading from a large file. However I need to decrease this process time, because the combobox values changes in a couple of minutes. So instead of reading and decoding from the text file each time, is there any way to read the file and decode it while app startup or something and when ever the value in combobox changes, then show the required text only?

Note: The values decoded are each time different and it depends on the value in combobox.

Hereby attaching my sample code so far.

```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf countup2)
        thread2.Start()
    End Sub

Private Sub countup2()
        Try
            ListView1.Items.Clear()
            ListView2.Items.Clear()
            ListView3.Items.Clear()
            ListView4.Items.Clear()
            ListView5.Items.Clear()


            Dim allVersions = New List(Of Version)
            Dim JSONb = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\sapi.txt")
            Dim values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(JSONb) 'Converts it to JObject

            For Each i In values("data").Children()

                If i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_type = "val1" And i.ToObject(Of Version).circleid.Contains(ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString) And i.ToObject(Of Version).operatorid.Contains(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString) Then
                    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_amount)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_validity)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_longdesc)
                    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
                End If


                If i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_type = "val2" And i.ToObject(Of Version).circleid.Contains(ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString) And i.ToObject(Of Version).operatorid.Contains(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString) Then
                    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_amount)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_validity)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_longdesc)
                    ListView2.Items.Add(lvi)
                End If


                If i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_type = "val3" And i.ToObject(Of Version).circleid.Contains(ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString) And i.ToObject(Of Version).operatorid.Contains(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString) Then
                    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_amount)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_validity)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_longdesc)
                    ListView3.Items.Add(lvi)
                End If


                If i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_type = "val4" And i.ToObject(Of Version).circleid.Contains(ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString) And i.ToObject(Of Version).operatorid.Contains(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString) Then
                    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_amount)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_validity)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_longdesc)
                    ListView4.Items.Add(lvi)
                End If


                If i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_type = "val5" And i.ToObject(Of Version).circleid.Contains(ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString) And i.ToObject(Of Version).operatorid.Contains(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString) Then
                    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_amount)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_validity)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToObject(Of Version).recharge_longdesc)
                    ListView5.Items.Add(lvi)
                End If
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does the content of the JSON change?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a desktop app? If so how much data is in each ListView? Depending on data load and refresh time, constantly clearing and re-adding items can kill performance.

Comment: @ArunCode Use breakpoints to debug this code and find out where it is spending most of the time. This will tell you if the time is being spent reading the file.

Comment: One optimisation you could make is to not read the text file into a string variable. Instead try deserialising directly from a file stream. Have a look at he following link for further details on json deserialisation optimization tips, http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm

Comment: `assuming this is because of reading from a large file` No, that doesnt not look like the problem.  I have a 1.8MB json with 43,000 items in it which is read and deserialized in less than .25 secs.  Manually parsing and creating lots of LVIs is likely where the time is.  A List of custom Objects which you preprpcess with LINQ to remove some "vals"(?) and a DGV using it as a datasource should be lots faster and lots less code